# directory separator not working or wrong site root path

Tags: php, file, absolute-path

I've posted a question last week about this, I've thought it was solved but no! Still having the same problem using the directory_separator, site_root and lib_path.

I'm working with Linux, and I am not sure I am adding the paths correctly. So my project is located in File System > var > www > html > photo_gallery. If I use echo dirname( **FILE** ) on index.php it echoes "/var/www/html/photo_gallery/public".

On the other hand, I am creating an initialize.php file with the required files (session.php, config.php, functions.php, user.php etc), and I am trying to create their absolute paths, but it keeps displaying this:

[image]

The code to define those paths is:

```
 defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'var'.DS.'www'.DS.'html'.DS.'photo_gallery');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

//load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");

//load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."functions.php");

//load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."session.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php");

//load database-related classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."user.php");
```

Am I setting the paths right? I've seen some other examples looking on google and some add 'C:' before they start to put the directory separator, others access to wamp.... So I am not convince I'm doing it right, because definitely it's not working.

This is my files structure:
[image]

And I am trying to use the absolute path in database.php:

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
```

On user.php:

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."database.php");
```

Does anyone had the same problem and have solve it? I've seen a few asking about the same, through the same tutorial, but I can't find a working solution.

Thank yo

Comment: Where is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`  defined?

Comment: in the first line on initalize.php

"defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);"

Comment: What file defines these constants? In your `database.php` file, have you got `require_one './config.php';` (assuming `config.php` is the file you've pasted above)

Comment: those constants are defined in initialize.php (so the code I've pasted is from initialize.php), So defining them there, If I try to include them in index.php within the admin folder, is not right to add  require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."functions.php"); to require functions.php? I mean.... am I understanding LIB_PATH in a wrong way? :S

Comment: You can't use `LIB_PATH` in `index.php` before you include `initialize.php`, it looks like you're trying to do that with `database.php`. How are you including `database.php` and `initialize.php` in `index.php`?

Comment: This is so frustrating.... I don't even know what I'm doing now.... :S give me a couple of minutes I find myself in my mess :/